# App asks for Google account password (WhenHub) - how can I verify authenticity?

Tags: applications, security, google-account

WhenHub is not the second app I've seen this happen, and it seriously rubs me the wrong way. When you start the app it given you a series of options to sign in (Google, Twitter, LinkedIn).

[image: Sign in]

When choosing any option, the app prompts the user to enter the **username and password** inside the app. This presumably sends the user to the given provider site. However, having some background on building apps I can easily see how I could create a look-alike of the Google sign-in page to hijack the users data.

[image: Real page?]

This is serious enough for me that I'm never going to be able to use this kind of app. Am I paranoid? Given the lack of a URL, is there any other way to verify that this page is indeed provided by Google and not being spoofed?

Comment: Asking the developer may help for getting a reason or at worst help him fix it is he is not aware of this concern

Comment: You could use a packet sniffing app to see if it is loading from Google, and then put in bad info and see if it's sent back to Google.  Without the app source you can't tell that is not being recorded by it as well, though.  But then again, how do you know your device manufacturer didn't add something to the OS to record everything anyways?  Bottom line is if you don't trust the software, its creators, or its publishers -- don't use it.